# including interactions in a mixed linear model in R (lme)

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I'm trying to test for the effect of soil moisture on transpiration rates.  I have plot-level data for 18 plots in 6 different stands of trees (3 plots x 6 stands). I want to treat "stand" as a random effect. There are reasons (genetic similarities within a stand, differences in elevation, species composition, etc.) to think that stands may differ in transpiration rates. Moisture varies by stand as well.

The simple model in made in R is:

`model<-lme(transpiration~moisture,random=~1|stand,data=data)`

Does this satisfy it? Or should I do:

`model<-lme(transpiration~moisture+moisture*stand,random=~1|stand,data=data)`

The ANOVA for both models returns significant *p*-values for moisture, but when I run the latter model, I get the following error message:

`In pf(Fval[i], nDF[i], dDF[i]) : NaNs produced`  ... the `NaN` is the *p*-value for `stand`, which has zero denominator degrees of freedom.

Comment: Is your question about which model is correct, or is it why you get NaN?

Comment: Which model is correct (although I'm also trying to figure out the d.f issue).  I'm new to using mixed models, and to using R. That said, I think the first model is appropriate. I want the power of 18 plots, but since the plots are clustered into groups of 3, I think it would be unfair to assume they are independent. Including stand as a random effect should take care of that, right?
I'm only interested in the main effect of moisture on transpiration, and don't care if the relationship between transpiration and moisture varies by across stands.